# Piedra, papel o tijera en Python

Tags: python

alguien me ayuda a entender el algoritmo empleado en este programa? No entiendo la parte del if-elif-else, entiendo el código pero no la lógica empleada en el programa, no soy muy bueno en matemáticas.

```py
import random

opciones = ['piedra', 'papel', 'tijera']
print('-' * 30)
print('Piedra, papel o tijera'.center(30))
print('-' * 30)
print('1. Piedra'.center(30))
print('2. Papel'.center(30))
print('3. Tijera'.center(30))
humano = int(input('\nIngrese una opción: '))
pc = random.randint(1,3)
resultado = 'Vos elegiste ' + opciones[humano - 1] + '.\n'
resultado += 'La computadora eligió ' + opciones[pc - 1] + '.\n'

print((humano - pc) % 3)
if (humano - pc) % 3 == 0:
    resultado += 'Empate'
elif (humano - pc) % 3 == 1:
    resultado += 'Ganaste'
else:
    resultado += 'Perdiste.'
    
print(resultado)
```

Comment: Vamos a poner un ejemplo: si humano elige "tijera" (Opción 3) y la computadora `random` elige tijera (opción 3) el resultado de `(humano - pc) =  3-3 igual 0` . Ahora al dar cero hacemos `0 divido 3 == resto 0` te da un resto cero y se cumple la primer condición `Empate`. Caso contrario salta al `elif` para ver si cumple esa siguiente condición. Ahora elegimos `opción 2` y la computadora la `opción 1`, cuando restamos `(2-1)` nos da 1. Ahora `1 divido 3` nos da `resto == 1` entonces `Ganaste`. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Entiendo como funciona el código pero no entiendo como fue pensado el algoritmo.